# jquery AJAX dynamically loading of image preview works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, image-processing

I am using jquery sortable to sort images. When the images are sorted, I send back the first image to load it into `img` tag (like a preview). This works fine. However, this is working only once, for the first time. When I sort the images again, it's not updating the preview.

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
  axis: 'x,y',
  containment: "parent",
  tolerance:'pointer',
  update: function(event, ui) {
    var item_order = new Array();
    $('.reorder-gallery li').each(function() {
      item_order.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "processes/sort.php",
      data: 'order='+item_order,
      cache: false,
      success: function(json){
        $("#dp").attr("src", json.dp); // WORKS ONLY ONCE
      }
    });
  }
}).disableSelection();

<div class="dp gradient-bg">
  <img src="<?php echo dp(); ?>" alt="" id="dp">
</div>
```

I tried adding a random string at the end like this:

`$("#dp").attr("src", json.dp + '?rand=' + Math.random()); // NOT WORKING EITHER`

Still, loads preview only once. I have to refresh the page to make it work again. Each time working only for the first time. What should be done?

Comment: Is your ajax called executed ?Did you check if `json.dp` actual has any value ?

Comment: Yes, it does. My PHP sends back the value. Each time a new image when the sorting is executed. I have verified it in the network response too. Also, that is the reason why I mentioned that it changes the preview at least for the first time (and the only time). However, I don't see why it doesn't do it the second time.

Comment: Also, I believe that one problem that can happen here is that I need to send back the sorting code along with the AJAX response to dynamically bind it with the element to make it work. However, I am trying to avoid this approach as of now to see if something better can done.

Comment: can you show html code as well ?

Comment: @Swati updated question with HTML code..!

Comment: This seems ok to me . Is there any other jquery code which might be causing this or related to this and you have not posted ?

Comment: No everything else seems fine. Even this code seems pretty fine. I was bound to post a question just because everything seems fine and I couldn't detect the error. Lol :D Anyways, I think the only option is to dynamically bind the script by calling it via AJAX and see if that works. Time dene ke liye thanks Swati :)

Comment: Okay testing done.. Just to inform you that by dynamically binding the sortable function and sending it back again on each AJAX call makes it work. Also, a silly mistake that I did here was that I was already calling it dynamically due to some earlier reasons which I had forgotten. All I had to do was to place the code `$("#dp").attr("src", json.dp);` in that re-called function too.